# GWT, is there any Gwt widgets that mange pagingif provided totalRecords, pageSize, visible page links?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

we have `SimplePager` but this for cell widgets, I want to know is there any widgets that help to do this thing:

if we have

```
totalRecords=100;
pageSize=3;
visiblePageLinks=5;
```

then the result will be like this

```
Page: [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [Next] out of 34 (note:34=100/3 +1)

when user clicking [Next] it will automatically turn to
Page: [previous] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [next]

if they click the last [Next], it will turn to:

Page: [previous] [31] [34] [33] [34] (note: no more [Next]

If user clicking [previous] then it will calculate backwards.
```

So is there any widget in Gwt that help to so that automatically, ex:

```
PagingWidget pagingWidget =new PagingWidget();
pagingWidget.setTotalRecords(100);
pagingWidget.setPageSize(3);
pagingWidget.setVisiblePageLinks(5);
flowPanel.add(pagingWidget); will show the gui similar to the one mentioned above?
```

Comment: Something you might be interested in http://code.google.com/p/gwt-advanced-table/ but I would still recommend using CellTable.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this one:

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/SimplePager.html

You can extend it to add more functionality, or you can write your own using the same ideas.

Answer (score 0):

you need extend AbstractPager not SimplePager.

because SimplePager can only show text.*check createText() in SimplePager.java.*

**table.setVisibleRange(start, pagesize)** is essence.and do like below extend AbstractPager

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
        VerticalPanel root=new VerticalPanel();
        RootPanel.get().add(root);
        List<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            values.add("value"+i);
        }

        final CellTable<String> table=new CellTable<String>();
        table.addColumn(new TextColumn<String>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(String object) {
                return object;
            }
        });


        ListDataProvider<String> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>();
        dataProvider.addDataDisplay(table);

        table.setRowCount(values.size());
        dataProvider.setList(values);

        final int psize=2;
        table.setPageSize(psize);
        table.setRowData(values);

        table.setVisibleRange(0, psize);

        HorizontalPanel horizontalPanel=new HorizontalPanel();
        int index=1;
        for(int i=0;i<values.size();i+=2){
            final int start=i;
            Button bt=new Button("page"+index,new ClickHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    table.setVisibleRange(start, psize);
                }

            });
            horizontalPanel.add(bt);
            index++;
        }

        root.add(table);
        root.add(horizontalPanel);
}
```